# Inserting HTML from server into DOM with angular2 (general DOM manipulation in Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, typescript

I would like to insert some HTML that I retrieve from my server into a DOM element in angular2. I can't seem to figure out the best/correct way to do this.

I can't just put {{my_data}} into a template because angular 2 will automatically escape the HTML.

I have attempted to write an html-unsafe directive which just assigns a value directly to innerHTML of an element:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/typings.d.ts" />

import {Directive} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';


@Directive({
    selector: "[html-unsafe]",
    properties: ['htmlUnsafe']
})
export class HtmlUnsafe{
    constructor(private elem: ElementRef){

    }

    set htmlUnsafe(value){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.elem.nativeElement.innerHTML = value;
        },0);
    }
}
```

So now in my template I have something like

```
<td [html-unsafe]="my_data"></td>
```

This works, but I am not sure it is the correct way to do this and the setTimeout seems like an odd workaround. Without the setTimeout it appears that `this.elem.nativeElement` does not actually refer to the DOM element but to some sort of temporary element.

Is there a more "correct" angular2 way to simply insert HTML into the DOM? Why do I need to wrap the DOM manipulation in a setTimeout?

Answer (score 8):

Reading this article http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/angularjs-2-0-sneak-preview-data-binding/ from November 2014.

`ng-bind-html becomes [innerHTML].`

You can try with this.

Comment: While this works for simple HTML tags like <b>Hello!</b> it does not work for Angular directives you have created yourself. In Angular 1.x you used $sce.trustAsHTML() combined with a custom directive that called $compile to compile Angular directives in your HTML. We need to know the equivalent of this in Angular 2.

Comment: I think that it is now `[innerHTML]`.

Comment: @VernJensen I have the same issue with custom directives, have you solved it ?

Comment: No, I realized that for my purposes, I could use an *ngFor loop to iterate over a series of custom objects that specify the HTML elements I want, with a series of *ngIf statements inside the loop -- one for each HTML directive I want to be able to create. (For instance, one for a <select> control, another *ngIf for a <textarea>, another for a custom ng2 directive that I've created, and so on.) This has turned out to work really well. If what I'm doing isn't clear, let me know, and I can post an answer with source code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in the following way:

```
<td bind-inner-html="my_data"></td>
```

Comment: I think that it is now `[innerHTML]`.